# Default access modifier for interface methods in Java 9?

Tags: java, interface, java-9

Java 9 allows us to have `private` methods in interface, which means that not explicitly marking `public` methods is no longer superfluous.

However, is it now mandatory to do so? I hope the specification still assumes `public abstract` as the default modifier for methods to maintain backward compatibility with earlier source code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Java 9 Language Specification says in §9.4::

> A method in the body of an interface may be declared `public` or `private` (§6.6). If no access modifier is given, the method is implicitly `public`. It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the `public` modifier for a method declaration in an interface.

Unfortunately, I can't find a link that does not lead to [a PDF, diffing the old and new JLS](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/9/java-se-9-pr-spec-01/java-se-9-jls-pr-diffs.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

What I was taught:

All members in an Interface are implicitly public and cannot be declared
with any other access modifier, unless specified below:

- Fields & all variables are public static final implicitly
- method signatures, default methods, (permitted as of Java 8) declared with the 'default' modifier.
- Static methods (permitted as of Java 8)
- Private methods (permitted as of Java 9) both static and non-static concrete methods can be private.
- Nested types.
- Method bodies exist only for default, private and static methods.

Source: Tim Buschalka's Learn Programming Academy

Also a very clear but somewhat long explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html